Portal 2 Build Error: The puzzle has too many items and cannot be built. Please remove some items and try again
I started building a map in Portal 2 Puzzle Maker, but every time I try to run my map, then I get the following error:

Build Error
The puzzle has too many items and cannot be built.
Please remove some items and try again.


But how can this be? I've barely put any items on the map. I literally just started building the map. I have seen other maps with way more items than mine. I have almost nothing on it as you can see here:


Why am I getting this error? What is causing this error?

I am struggling to find the resource but I believe there is an internal complexity value, but you should try keeping the developer console (~) open when you load the level, it may shed some light. Additionally, you can try Opening the Level with the Hammer Editor to understand what else could be going on as Hammer has more details for you :)

I had completely forgotten about the Puzzle Maker; building with that editor is obviously much easier than figuring out Hammer :)

From the Valve Developer Portal 2 Puzzle Maker common issues page (retained original links):

Item Entity Costs
Large puzzles with many items may result in a "too many items" error. The item limit is set at 1750 items, though what this actually refers to is what are known as entities within the Source engine. Many of the test elements are actually comprised of multiple entities, the total cost of which is noted on their individual pages.
If you receive this error, you can see the error message noting the exact number of entities your map used by opening the Developer Console. For further information on troubleshooting this error, there is a detailed thread for it on the Portal 2 Steam Forums.

The linked entities page leads to a generic Source Engine entities page - this page will be more useful. On the right-hand site all categories of entities ("Objects") are mentioned: these linked pages show overviews of the specific entities and their costs.

For sake of completion, the screenshot shows 2 tractor beams (8 cost each), 49 piston platforms (44 cost each) and one track platform (13 cost) with 18 rails (1 cost each) for a total of 2223 items.
